# iOS Detect setting of system "Settings/Cellular/Cellular Data" master switch?

Tags: ios, core-telephony

As of iOS9, the capability to check the setting to enable/disable use of cellular data for your app (Settings/Cellular/AppName) is available using Apple's CTCellularData class. The following code will set cellularDataRestrictedState when it is run initially and then set it and log whenever it changes:

```
import CoreTelephony
var cellularDataRestrictedState = CTCellularDataRestrictedState.restrictedStateUnknown
let cellState = CTCellularData.init()
cellState.cellularDataRestrictionDidUpdateNotifier = { (dataRestrictedState) in
    if cellularDataRestrictedState != .restrictedStateUnknown { // State has changed - log to console
        print("cellularDataRestrictedState: " + "\(dataRestrictedState == .restrictedStateUnknown ? "unknown" : dataRestrictedState == .restricted ? "restricted" : "not restricted")")
    }
    cellularDataRestrictedState = dataRestrictedState
}
```

Unfortunately (as of iOS11) this seems to check only the state of the app's switch - if your app's switch is set to enabled and the user switches the Cellular Data master switch to disabled, this API will *still* return the app's state as being "not restricted".  This would seem to be a bug to me, unless there is a way to detect the state of the master switch.

Is there a separate mechanism to query the state of the system "Settings/Cellular/Cellular Data" master switch?

Comment: Hi Paul! Did you find solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: I have not seen a solution, so far.  I filed a RADAR (36412628) and gave Apple sample code to reproduce the issue.  Apple Developer Relations asked for me to send a sysdiagnose, which in this case would be pointless - they can reproduce the problem easily using the code I already supplied.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was for me to check iOS network names and in the same time  usage cellular data for my app but I'm not sure if it's really good idea. There is not so much information provided about it.

```
   cellularData?.cellularDataRestrictionDidUpdateNotifier = { (dataRestrictedState) in
        if dataRestrictedState == .restricted { // State has changed - log to console
                self.checkIfCellularDataRestricted()
        }
    }

    func pdpIpExists() -> Bool {
//        ap1, en0, en1 are names of the interfaces on iOS as well as on Mac.
//        pdp_ip interfaces are those that are used for 3G and cellular data
    var pdpIpExists = false
    var address: String?
    var ifaddr: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>? = nil
    if getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 {
        var ptr = ifaddr
        while ptr != nil {
            defer { ptr = ptr?.pointee.ifa_next }

            let interface = ptr?.pointee
            let addrFamily = interface?.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_family
            if addrFamily == UInt8(AF_INET) || addrFamily == UInt8(AF_INET6) {

                if let interface = interface, String(cString: interface.ifa_name).contains("pdp_ip") {
                    pdpIpExists = true
                    var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
                    getnameinfo(interface.ifa_addr, socklen_t((interface.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_len)), &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count), nil, socklen_t(0), NI_NUMERICHOST)
                    address = String(cString: hostname)
                }
            }
        }
        freeifaddrs(ifaddr)
    }
    //if cellular data is on, set notifyIfCellularDataRestricted to true, to notify next time when cellular data is off
    if pdpIpExists && cellularData?.restrictedState == .notRestricted {
        TWUserDefaults.notifyIfCellularDataRestricted = true
    }
    return pdpIpExists
}
```

Comment: It's incorrect for devices with multiple sim slots (f.e. iphone 11 contains physical slot and esim). By default internet traffic goes through interface named **pdp_ip0**. If you change sim for using internet this sim will bind to interface **pdp_ip0**. It means that you need check only interface **pdp_ip0**. If you turn off global switch for cellular data system disables pdp_ip0 but interface pdp_ip1 is availalbe. It seems to me that it's bug in ios that appeared after adding support of multiple sim-cards.